# Problems accessing global variable?

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

In my DataCell.h I declared global variable before interface:

```
extern NSInteger MYGlobalVariable;
```

In my DataCell.m

I set the value of variable:

```
NSInteger MYGlobalVariable = 35;
```

In my other class MyTableViewController.m

I imported the DataCell.h and then tried to set value of int to a label.

```
_testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , MYGlobalVariable];
```

However when I try to build application I get the errors:

- Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_MYGlobalVariable", referenced from: MyTableViewController
- error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Is ```DataCell.h``` being imported via a static library?

Comment: @EllNeal No. It's defined in `DataCell.m`.

Comment: Import DataCell.h in MyTableViewController.h instead.

Comment: Where exactly did you define this variable in DataCell.m? I'm guessing you didn't actually define it in global scope.

Comment: You can declare `MYGlobalVariable` as a property of `DataCell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based in what you've said above, you're doing everything right. This, I suspect one of the details above doesn't match your code.

Does the `extern` declaration match the variable declaration? (e.g. You didn't accidentally spell it differently, etc.)

Is the variable declaration in the .m accidentally prefixed with the `static` keyword?

Is your `NSInteger MyGlobalVariable = 35` line actually inside a method? If so, that would just be declaring a variable local to that method. Make sure it's not inside any curly braces; it should be floating at the outermost level of the file. You can put it before the `@implementation` block, if that helps.

If none of that fixes it, then you may need to show us your actual code so we can see better what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes you were right I declared the variable inside method. But what is the point of global variable if I cannot set data inside the method. Currently this is just some static data?

Comment: You can set it inside a method, but it has to be declared outside it. To set it, you would just to `MyGlobalVariable = 28;`, leaving off the type name. Just like `int x = 3;` declares a new variable named x, and `x = 3;` assigns a new value to an existing variable named x.

Comment: You are right and works fine, just one more question would I be able to use NSMutable Array in same manner?

Comment: Well, sorta. You won't be able to declare the mutable array with an initial value, because a mutable array is not a constant. But you can declare it with no initial value (e.g. `NSMutableArray *myGlobalArray;` outside any method) and then give it an initial value inside some `-init` method or something.

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to write extern keyword in you DataCell.h file.

Just declare it as `NSInteger MYGlobalVariable;` before the interface and then in your TableViewController.m file declare a variable `extern NSInteger MYGlobalVariable;`.

This will work!

Comment: No, this will make a separate global variable for everyone who imports it. If more than one .m file imports it, you'll get linker errors due to multiple global variables having the same name.

Comment: Correct; external doesn't make multiple globals. But putting the non-extern declaration in the header is the problem; each file that imports that header basically pastes the entre header into their .m file, and since the erosion in the header doesn't say `extern`, each of them will try to declare their own copy of it.

Comment: Basically, you've got it backwards; you want the `extern` version in the header where it will be imported, and only one copy of the actual non-extern declaration. Which is what the OP said they did.

Comment: I checked it! There is no error that I am getting! and as per the documentation of Objective-C, this is how it is to be used. else its your wish OP!

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala this is wrong the `extern` should be in the header file, BJ Homer is correct. Can you share this documentation?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala What's even more bizarre is that declaring `NSInteger foo; NSInteger foo;` in global scope twice in the same file isn't causing an error. I'm not sure why, and I'll continue to look into it. It appears that your suggestion is actually working in current Xcode, but that's against the C spec as I understand it. My suggestion is in line with the spec and also works.

Comment: AHA. It's treating them all as forward declarations of the variable. While this works by coincidence, there are cases where it will break. (I'm trying to find a concise example right now.)

Comment: The simplest example I have right now of where it breaks: it will break if the header is imported by any `.mm` or `.cpp` file, because C++ has stricter rules about the use of the `extern` keyword.

Comment: @BJHomer i am not saying it to declare twice in a file! that obviously doesn't make any sense. what I am saying is, declare a variable global in any file and use it in any other file by adding extern keyword before it.
say for ex: you declare a variable int cars; in one file(file1.h or .m) and you want to use it in (file2.h or m). so to do that you have to declare extern int cars; in file2.h or m

Comment: Yes, I understand. My point is that the `extern` must be visible by everyone wanting to use it; if it's declared in file1.m, file2.m needs an `extern` either in a header it imports or in file2.m itself, or else it won't think it's an extern declaration. Remember, when compiling file2.m, the compiler doesn't even look at file1.m. An extern declaration there won't affect how file2.m is compiled.

Comment: [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class)

Check the definition of extern in this link! :)

Comment: I have the pdf of Objective C and obviously i can't upload it, otherwise you would have known! wait I'll give you the name of the book!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27408/discussion-between-bj-homer-and-burhanuddin-sunelwala)

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to pass the variable to the class by doing the following.

MyTableViewController.h

```
#import DataCell.h //At top...

@property (strong, nonatomic) DataCell *datacell;
```

MyTableViewController.m

```
@synthesize datacell;

_testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , dataCell.MYGlobalVariable];
```

Comment: MYGlobalVariable is not a property of dataCell!!

Comment: When I do this I get error:  MYGlobalVariable not found on object type DataCell *

Comment: Did you make sure `NSInteger MYGlobalVariable = 35;` is in `@implementation`?